# monit call exec on process recovery

Tags: monit

What I would like to do, is the following:

- if process-x fails (to (re)start) then execute cmd-x
- if it recovers then execute cmd-y

For the alerting via E-mail, a notificaton is sent per default on recovery. For the exec method however, I can not find a way to make this work. If I try this in the monitrc:

```
check process proc_x with pidfile /var/run/proc_x.pid
   start program = "/bin/sh -c '/etc/init.d/Sxxproc_x start'"
   stop  program = "/bin/sh -c '/etc/init.d/Sxxproc_x stop'"
   if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then exec "<some error cmd>"
   else if succeeded then exec "<some restore cmd>"
```

this results in a "*syntax error 'else'*". If I remove the else line, the error command is called as expected. Apparently, the 'else' can not be used for the *restarts* test. But how can I add to execute a command is program starting succeeds or recovers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to the answer to this topic:

[get monit to alert first and restart later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081180/get-monit-to-alert-first-and-restart-later)

The "*if not exist for ...*" with corresponding "*else*" did the trick for me to report the recover. The error report is separate. My monitrc code now:

```
check process proc_x with pidfile /var/run/proc_x.pid
   start program = "/bin/sh -c '/etc/init.d/Sxxproc_x start'"
   stop  program = "/bin/sh -c '/etc/init.d/Sxxproc_x stop'"
   if 1 restart within 1 cycle then exec "<some error cmd>"
       repeat every 1 cycle
   if not exist for 3 cycles then restart
   else if succeeded 2 times within 2 cycles then exec "<some restore cmd>"
```